# Modify UIPickerView as it appears from UIWebView action

Tags: ios

I am currently upgrading an app that has a list in a `UIWebView`. When the link is clicked inside the `UIWebView`, a `UIPickerView` is called on the app itself. The `UIPickerView` has default view settings.

The issue is that the header text of the `UIPickerView` is white against a light background. I need to modify this header text so that it is easily readable.

I have tried to set the `UIWebView` as a `UIPickerViewDelegate`, but none of the delegate methods are called.

How can I customize the view of the `UIPickerView` that is called?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684489/how-to-get-object-referece-of-uipickerview-when-it-create-through-html-select-ta help?

Comment: I had tried that solution previously, but it only seems to detect when the keyboard is called. I set a breakpoint in that solution and it was not hit when the UIPickerView came up.