# override UIView setFrame globally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, objective-c-category

I want to make sure none of my views are misaligned and hence would want to use CGRectIntegral  while setting frame on all the uiviews. But I don't want to make it so that all the devs just set the frame like they would normally (eg. view.frame = aCGRect) and it magically works. I tried to add a category and then override the setFrame: method for UIView but that (Obviously!) creates an infinite loop :

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
  self.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than adding a utility function?

Comment: You can do it like : `-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
  super.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame)
}`

Comment: @MidhunMP You should never override a method in a category.

Comment: @rmaddy: I thought he is subclassing the UIView

Comment: Thanks guys but I can't subclass the view

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Note this can create some funny effects during animations.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for development/diagnosis, you could perhaps [swizzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371601/how-do-i-implement-method-swizzling) the original method (`-[UIView setFrame:]`) but call the original method in your implementation, passing the adjusted rect.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a release solution and not just a debug solution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this globally in release.